# where should I put the EF entity and data annotations in asp.net mvc + entity framework project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-3, project-organization

So I have a DataEntity class generated by EntityFramework4 for my sqlexpress08 database. This data context is exposed via a WCF Data Service/Odata to silverlight and win forms clients.

**Should the data entities + edmx file (generated by EF4) go in a separate class library?**

The problem here then is I would specify data annotations for a few entities and then some of them would require specific MVC attributes (like CompareAttribute) so the class library would also reference mvc dlls. There also happen to be entity users which will be encapsulated or wrapped into an IIdentity in the website. So its pretty tied to the mvc website. **Or Should it maybe go in a Base folder in the mvc project itself?**

Mostly the website is data driven around the database, like approve users, change global settings etc. The real business happens in the silverlight and win forms apps.

Im using mvc3 rc2 with Razor.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should the data entities + edmx file (generated by EF4) go in a separate class library?

IMHO all data access logic which is specific to some data access technology (in your case Entity Framework) should go into a separate assembly. There should be no MVC specific assemblies referenced there.

In your ASP.NET MVC application you would then reference this assembly and write view models. It is those view models that will contain any MVC specific attributes. Then you could map between your model classes and those view models which would be passed to the view. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could be used to facilitate this task.

Comment: Hmm Ive heard of this before. One more question, so In my Mvc project would I have something like `IRepository` ..its implementation would query up the entity objects and  then return **ViewModels** ??

Comment: @giddy, IRepository should not return view models. It should work with domain models. The mapping between those domain models and view models should be performed by the controller. As far as its location, well, IMHO it is better suited in your data access layer rather than your MVC application.